# Should we use ob_start() in WordPress short code

Tags: theme-development

We have used our short code like bellow

```
   ob_start();
    $rand = uniqid();


    ?>
    <div class="faq-item-sm panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#faq<?php echo $rand; ?>" data-parent="#accordionFaq" class="collapsed">  <?php echo $question; ?><span class="caret-toggle closed">–</span><span class="caret-toggle opened">+</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="faq<?php echo $rand; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if($faq_active == true){ echo 'in';} ?> ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <?php echo $answer; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
```

Is it best Practice to use multiple times echo and ob_start in php. Is this effect in Performance.

Answer (score 1):

It’s one way to do it.

I like it, because it allows you to write HTML code pretty easily and it makes it pretty obvious and easy to maintain. But it’s just opinion based, I guess.

It doesn’t harm your performance to much. You shouldn’t use output buffering to generate whole content of the site, because you want to start sending response to the browser as soon as possible, but this is not the case here...

You can also:

- prepare the HTML output by concatenating strings (it’s harder to read and easier to make some html errors, IMHO),
- use some “view” pattern

Comment: Normally we have developed many shortcode for our theme. Each shortcode we have used this way , as it is easy for us to ready. But in am confused by some articles that it impacts on performance or load time. Is it true

Comment: @ArifurRahman I've already mentioned it in my answer... The impact is not so big, if you use it only for shortcodes...